# Different Android Action bar tab widths

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Is it possible to create action bar tabs that have different widths? Everything I try results in all tabs having the same width, which fits the longest tab's text.  I am creating a custom action bar and every tab should fit it's text (like wrap content).

I have been browsing a lot for the answer but I haven't really found it.